# blur the side of the site

Tags: html, css

blure side site
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/giurR.jpg

how to blur the side of a website
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIgfz.png

```
#main-style {
position: relative;
}
#main-style::after {
content: "";
width: 100%;
height: 135%;
position: absolute;
top: -30px;
left: 0;
overflow: hidden;
filter: blur(5px);
}
```

this code don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the code where you wrote: `filter: blur(5px);` with `backdrop-filter: blur(5px)`

Explanation:
The code you wrote earlier works by taking a snapshot of the element and display the snapshot with blurred effect at the place of the element.
`backdrop-filter`, instead blurs the background of the element.

Note:
As of now, `backdrop-filter` does not work with Firefox Browsers.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/36uU0Rz how to blure side

Comment: I saw the image. You need to first create the box/area which should be blurred. You can create it using a `div` element, and add position properties as you want. Once you have done creating the overlay/area you want to blur, add the line `backdrop-filter: blur(10px);` to the `div` element.